# Запятая перед "И", почему она в данном случае?

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис, запятые

Есть предложение: "Чтоб вы понимали: у меня загорели только плечи, и то по дороге домой" 
Интуитивно я понимаю, что в данном предложении перед "и" обязательно должна быть запятая, но почему? Какое обоснование? Это ССП, состоящее из двух простых предложений: "загорели плечи" и "по дороге домой" (односоставное)? Или "по дороге домой" - это обстоятельство образа действия? Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться. Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Чтоб вы понимали: у меня загорели только плечи, **и (да и) то по дороге домой.***

В данном случае  союз И является **присоединительным**, он синонимичен союзу ДА И.

Присоединяет обособленное обстоятельство.

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=120#pp120

1. Присоединительные члены предложения, которые содержат дополнительные разъяснения или замечания, вводимые в середину либо в конец высказывания, выделяются (или отделяются) запятыми (реже используются тире, точка, многоточие). Такие конструкции обычно присоединяются словами даже, особенно, в особенности, например, главным образом, в частности, в том числе, притом, и притом, причём, **и (‘и притом’), да, да и**, да и вообще, да и только